# Xero error: 403 forbidden when POST'ing an Invoice

Tags: xero-api

I'm setting up API calls to test retrieving and creating Invoices to and from Xero.  I've set up the oAuth2 and I can retrieve from the Demo Co with no errors.

However, when trying a POST with the same credentials and authentication, I get:

```
{
    "Type": null,
    "Title": "Forbidden",
    "Status": 403,
    "Detail": "AuthenticationUnsuccessful",
    "Instance": "f60c6b6e-7f3d-4941-9a8e-654495d3e07b",
    "Extensions": {}
}
```

What have I done wrong?  Thank you

Comment: Does your scope allow invoices to be created?

Comment: Yes. My scopes are set to:
accounting.transactions offline_access

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend ensuring the access_token you are passing to that API call has the required scopes: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/scopes - to POST an invoice you will need the scope `accounting.transactions` - to quickly check the actual scopes on a token you can decode your JWT (aka `access_token`) using some decryption libraries, or use the site https://jwt.io/ at your discretion.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, My scopes are set to: accounting.transactions offline_access

Comment: Cool looks like you got it sorted. Have to make sure you are passing the `xero-tenant-id` to every api call to a protected resource.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your responses.
I hadn't realised that the {{xero-tenant Id}} had not been added to the Headers in POST Invoices in Postman.

Manually adding that in fixed the bug